# Invalidating existing users from RDS snapshot and creating new one while creating new instance from snapshot

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, devops

While creating new RDS aurora instance from snapshot I want to delete all existing users and add new users. I didn't find any aws cli command for this specific purpose. So I can invalidate all existing users and add new one.
Does AWS provides this kind of functionality? If not then how we can do this while creating new RDS instance from snapshot?

Answer (score 1):

That's not practical.  RDS doesn't manipulate your database at such a deep level.

In MySQL (including Aurora), stored program objects -- views, triggers, events, stored procedures, and stored functions -- have a `DEFINER` user associated with them, and run in some cases in definer context -- where the permissions available to the program are only those of the definer.  Those users must continue to exist, otherwise the objects are unusable and must be redefined (dropped and recreated) by a different user.

Comment: I mean I want to delete some of the users not all users like system user  DEFINER.

Comment: `DEFINER` is not a system user.  Run `SHOW CREATE VIEW` (or event, procedure, trigger, or function) on one of your objects and you should see something like `CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED
                      DEFINER=\`someuser\`@\`%\`
                      SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW
                      \`v1\` AS SELECT...` The restored snapshot needs all referenced users to exist, with their same privileges.